# Does anyone have a code example of AES encryption in python on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have a query string I need to encrypt using AES in CBC mode with zero padding, before finally encoding it to base64 and I need to run this on Google App Engine in Python.

I've had a look around and can't be sure what works in GAE and what doesn't, I'm also finding it hard to get example code of some of those I believe should work, such as (http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/).

**Does anyone have a code example or link to one for AES encryption in python on Google App Engine?**

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is [supported on App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#PyCrypto). I would recommend checking out examples and docs for PyCrypto - they should function the same on App Engine as everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Appengine has a limit on source files ( less than 1000) and doesn't run python modules with C extensions. Given this limitations I would recommend you SlowAES (http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/) which is ( for Python) only one source  file and is written in pure python.

Comment: Thanks, you don't happen to know of a code example and/or documentation for this? I've search with no luck myself.